# price discount for quantity html/java/php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I need a slider on my "Prices" page, that slider will adjust the Quantity just so the customer can get a instant quote for the service..

The quantity should go from 1 to 500 or 1000 but a box to enter the quantity next to it would help.

Another problem is I need different prices for different quantity ranges,

example:

```
quantity=1-3 price=20/unit
quantity=4-10 price=17/unit
quantity=11-50 price=15/unit
```

and so on..

so far I have this, I'm not even sure if I'm miles away or very close and don't realize it... please help.

```
    <input type="range" min="1" max="1000" value="1" step="1" onchange="sliderChange(this.value)" style="margin-left:5%; margin-right:5%; width:90%;" />
    <br />
    <br />Slider Value = <span id="sliderStatus">1</span> 
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
      var x = 30;
      var z = x * y;


      if (0 < x) {
        var y = 13;
      }
      if (10 < x < 21) {
        var y = 12;
      }
      if (20 < x < 31) {
        var y = 11;
      }
      if (30 < x < 41) {
        var y = 10;
      }
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = z;
    </script>
```

Comment: you are calling a function(sliderChange(this.value)) on the change event of the slider, but i don't see that function in your javascript.  are you missing some code?  and your javascript is... a mess :(   for one, you should use meaningful names for your variables (not x, y, and z)...

Answer (score 1):

Your html calls the sliderChange function so your JS should be

```
function sliderChange(number) {
    if(number > 10 && number < 51) {
        $(".demo").html((number*15));
    } else if(number > 4 && number < 11){
        $(".demo").html((number*17));
    } else {
        $(".demo").html((number*20));
    }
}
```

Then any higher quantity discounts can be made with the copy and paste of the `else if` block and simply change those numbers to the number you want to have e.g("number > 50 && number < 100)

Comment: Alternatively, you can have no else block and only have else ifs for all options after the first one

Comment: tq, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a start which should start you on the right path to completion: https://jsfiddle.net/adebu2bs/

html:

```
<input id="slider" type="range" min="1" max="1000" value="1" step="1" style="margin-left:5%; margin-right:5%; width:90%;" />
<br />
<br />Slider Value = <span id="sliderStatus">1</span> 
<p id="demo"></p>
```

jquery:

```
$("#slider").on('change',function() {
var selectedQty = $(this).val();
$('#sliderStatus').text(selectedQty);


var itemTotal = 0;
 switch (true) {
    case (selectedQty <= 3) :
        itemTotal = 20 * selectedQty;
        break;
    case (selectedQty <= 10) :
        itemTotal = 17 * selectedQty;
        break;
    default:
        itemTotal = 25 * selectedQty;
        break;
  }
  alert(itemTotal);
  $('#demo').text(itemTotal);
});
```

Comment: You Sir are a God!!! i have lost 40+ hours so far trying to find patches of code to put together for this and nothing worked, you saved me big time :)  Incredible, I'm speechless

Answer (score 0):

You need a function to call your javascript.  Add a button like this:

`<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>`

Then inside your script, call that function

```
    function myFunction() {
         var x = document.getElementById("myRange").value;
         // your code with prices
    }
```